# Emulate Motion API on an emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am developing an app which uses a accelerometer + compass sensor and I would like to run it the emulator. The problem with that is that Mango only allow to emulate Acceleromter, but it doesn't to emulate `Motion`.

I thought of creating a Mock object using the same base class as Motion does (SensorBase - abstract class), however it's constructor is internal and I can't inherit from it :/

Any ideas how to overcome it?

Comment: Similar question: [WP7 Mock Microsoft.Devices.Sensors.Compass when using the emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629453/wp7-convert-accelometer-and-compass-data-to-mock-motion-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by wrapping a Motion service inside an object which exposes the functionality of the motion service using ReactiveExtensions.

So in the end I would simple have to emulate a sequence of numbers.